# How to use return in for loop in a function?

Tags: swift, function, for-loop

I have a code below, but I am yielding an error that says

> missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

```
func returnMultipleGreetings (name: String...) -> String {
    for names in name {
        return names
    }
}
```

How do I edit this code to remove the error?

Comment: You have to return in the scope of the function, you make a variable that can hold what you're looping through and then return it.

Comment: You have to have a String returned for all exit paths. So you need a return after your loop in case some logic in the loop hits the return. In your example you would always return the first value. Your question is also confusing because you have switched the plurality of "names" and "name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try source code:

```
func returnMultipleGreetings (name: String...) -> String {
    var result = ""
    for names in name {
        result = names
    }
    return result 
}
```

Hope it's OK.

Answer (score 4):

You must return within the scope of the function. NOT within the scope of the `for-loop`, which is where you currently have it. If you are not familiar with "scope" then do some reading as it is an important topic to understand. As of right now, `returnMultipleGreetings` cannot "see" `return names`. The following should fix your error...

```
func returnMultipleGreetings (name: String...) -> String {
     for names in name {
   //iterate thru array within loop
     }
  //return AFTER loop finishes
 return names
}
```